# When to use Multidimension arrays

Tags: c#, .net

In C# the concept of Multidimension arrays are pretty cool. But I don't understand when to use them. Like in what type of applications does this concept is used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not to sound trite but you use multidimensional arrays when you have multidimensional data.

Matrices are a common example but it could just as easily be a game board (eg Chess) or as the data model for an N-dimensional maze or a tally or anything really.

Answer (score 5):

One common use is matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you want to program a chess game. How would you represent the board with an unidimensional array?

Comment: Usually in chess programming board is not represented in a 8X8 array. its extremely inefficient

Comment: With a 64 items long array :p (i'm not syaing it's easy but... it's possible)

Comment: Yes, though it's worth pointing out that a unidimensional array is simply *less convenient* in this case - it doesn't prevent you doing anything. Also, chess games more often than not use bitboards for representing the board.

Comment: @Umair: It's not inefficient in all cases. Most chess AIs use a combination of board representations, one of them often being a 2D array.

Comment: "Usually in chess programming board is not represented in a 8X8 array" sorry, just wanted to give an intuitive example. Maybe a tic-tac-toe board? :-)

Comment: @Umair: explain to me exactly how an 8x8 aray is "extremely inefficient".

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/chess2/page2.asp
http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/chess2/page3.asp

Comment: @Umair, those links show some extreme optimisation. Inefficiency != Can be optimized.

Answer (score 2):

As a side point, you can either use multidimensional arrays (int[,]) or jagged arrays (int[][]). The former can be initialized in one step, but requires a larger contiguous block of memory and is slower to access, whereas the latter is more memory-friendly as the sub-arrays can be spread over the address space, each sub-array can be a different length, and all single-dimensional arrays (SZarrays) have special optimizations in the CLR. However, you do need to initialize each dimension separately with jagged arrays:

```
int[][] jagged = new int[5][];
for (int i=0; i<jagged.Length; i++)
{
    jagged[i] = new int[10];    // length can be different for each sub-array, if needed
}
```

multidimensional arrays are initialized all at once

```
int[,] mArray = new int[5,10];
```

Comment: I had no idea C# had "multidimensional arrays". Good to know, even if I do never have occassion to use them. Thanx for the fish. Keith.

Comment: You've got one point wrong. Multidimensional arrays are *faster* to access, because jagged arrays require double indirection and null checks in addition to bounds checks.

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure others can provide many different examples, I work with robots and one of the many task robots perform is palletizing, placing item in a row and column formation on a pallet. Each location on the pallet is a set 2 or even 3 dimension indexes of an array.

locationArrayt[ row , column]

We also use them for multilingual applications. An array of strings represent the different error messages, the second index is the language.

message[errorNumber, language]

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of Java might enlighten you... it reads a file into a two-dimensional array. It's part of my MazeOfBolton solution (google it).

```
  /**
   * Reads the file into a char[rows][cols] matrix.
   * @param String filename - the name of the file to read
   * @return a two-dimensional array of chars containing file contents.
   */
  private static char[][] readMatrix(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
      input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
      String line = null;
      while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null ) {
        lines.add(line);
      }
      int rows = lines.size();
      char[][] matrix = new char[rows][];
      for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = lines.get(i).toCharArray();
      }
      return matrix;
    } finally {
      if(input!=null)input.close();
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:** I should say **why** I used a matrix... especially as I had to built a List to get the array... Huh? Why not just use the List? The short answer is **speed**.

Accessing an array (of however many dimensions) is implemented (under the hood) as "index arithmetic" (aka pointer arithmetic), so not only is it accessing an array element [O(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), it's **fast** O(1)... much much faster than the equivalent *arrayList.get(int index)* (when you do so a couple-of-million times)... and in the (admitedly artificial) world of algorithm racing, speed is everything.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 0):

A good example of a 2 dimensional array would be a bitmap image. Imagine each pixel in the picture taking up one block of the `Pixel[1024][768]` array. So to find out what colour the pixel in the top left hand corner of the screen was you would look at `Pixel[0][0]`.

3 dimensional arrays require more visualisation, but a classic example would be  modelling points in space.

I used a 2 dimensional array in a quick and dirty Hold 'Em simulator I wrote to represent decisions preflop, it looked a bit like this;

```
_Open = new char[][] 
{             //  2    3    4    5    6   7   8   9   T   J   Q   K   A
    new char [] {'P', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','F','F','F','F','F','F','P','P'}, // 2
    new char [] {'F', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'F','F','F','F','F','F','F','P','P'}, // 3 
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'P', 'F', 'F','F','F','F','F','F','F','P','P'}, // 4
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'P', 'F','F','F','F','F','F','F','P','P'}, // 5
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'P','F','F','F','F','F','F','P','P'}, // 6
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','P','F','F','P','F','F','P','P'}, // 7 
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','F','P','P','P','P','F','P','P'}, // 8
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','F','F','P','P','P','P','P','P'}, // 9
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','F','F','F','P','P','P','P','P'}, // T
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','F','F','F','F','P','P','P','P'}, // J
    new char [] {'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','F','F','P','P','P','P','P','P'}, // Q
    new char [] {'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'}, // K
    new char [] {'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'}  // A
};
```

Using 0 to represent 2 and 12 to represent Ace. So if the simulator detected Ace, King it would check _Open[12][11] see 'P' (meaning 'push' or 'all-in') and act accordingly